# Vue router - beforeEach, detect click on same path

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a beforeeach on my routes

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  store.commit('sidebar_open', false);
  next();
})
```

all it does is close the sidebar when any route is clicked.

```
<router-link
  :key="$route.path"
  to="home"
>
 Home
</router-link>
```

The issue I am having is when I open the sidebar and click the same link, because the route is not changing the **beforeEach** is not called. How can I force vuerouter to detect any change?

Comment: You can trigger a method in sidebar component when the sidebar item is clicked. The sidebar is close when sidebar component render first time then when the sidebar item is clicked, toggle the sidebar.

Comment: yes but I don't really want to.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and here's *my 2 cents*.

From a UX stand, it's not a good solution to toggle the sidebar *"on sidebar link/item click"*.

Even if the sidebar is open, and you close it by clicking on the link that's points on the current path, how would you open the sidebar again?

As from my situation, I put the same logic in my `router.js`:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  store.commit('toggleSidebar', true)
  //other logic
})
```

And in my `Sidebar.vue` component I only have the computed method to fetch the current value `toggleSidebar`:

```
<template>
  <aside :class="{close: getSidebar}">
    <!-- other markup -->
  </aside>
</template>

...

computed: {
  getSidebar() {
    return this.$store.state.isSidebarClosed
  }
}
```

And now, to toggle the sidebar I have a `Navigation.vue` components (header) that has a button to do it:

```
<button type="button" @click="toggleSidebar">
   <span v-if="sidebarStatus" class="hamburger-icon"></span>
   <span v-else class="close-icon"></span>
</button>

...

methods: {
  toggleSidebar() {
    this.$store.commit('toggleSidebar', !this.$store.state.isSidebarClosed)
  }
},
computed: {
  sidebarStatus() {
    return this.$store.state.isSidebarClosed
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.